# new GoogleAnalytics Asynchronous tracking and Flash ExternalInterface.call

Tags: actionscript-3, google-analytics

I'm implementing Google analytics on a current project.

Apparently the code has been updated to a new asynchronous syntiax, so my old actionscript code doesn't work.
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html
This was my old code

```
ExternalInterface.call("pageTracker._trackEvent", CATEGORY,ACTION,LABEL, VALUE);
```

Can anyone tell me how I would format the above to work with the new asynchronous style of tracking?

Comment: You can still use the pageTracker code, as long as you're consistent in using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', CATEGORY,ACTION, Opt_LABEL, Opt_VALUE])");
```